# Prove that a subset of a linearly independent set is a linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

> Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of a finite dimensional space $V$.  Let $S_1 \subset S$, then prove that $S_1$ is linearly independent.

I have looked all through my textbook, but I have no idea how to solve this proof, or for that matter, even where to start.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Write down the definition of being linearly independent. (Add it here to your question!)

Step 2: There is no step 2 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume not then S is also not linearly independent. So you are done by contradiction