# (Could somebody check my) Proof that a subset of a linearly independent set is also L.I.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

In typing the title I was recommended two links, [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052135/prove-that-a-subset-of-a-linearly-independent-set-is-a-linearly-independent-set) and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280096/prove-that-any-finite-subset-of-a-linearly-independent-set-is-linearly-independe), which touch on this and provide hints but don't go all the way, so I was hoping just to check that what I have is correct.

**Statement:** Any subset U of a set of linearly independent vectors V is linearly independent.

**Proof by contradiction:** Suppose the subset is linearly dependent,

$$\exists \alpha_u\neq 0:\sum\alpha_u\bf{u} = 0$$

But then, if $V = U \oplus W$, for some vector $\textbf{v}\in V$:

$$\exists \alpha_u\neq 0:\sum_{u\in U}\alpha_u\textbf{u} +\sum_{w\in W}0\cdot\textbf{w} = 0$$

which implies that the vectors of V are linearly independent, a contradiction. So U must also be linearly independent.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: It's almost good, but note that it's incorrect to write $V=U\oplus W$, since neither $U$ nor $V$ is a linear space. Just let $W=V\setminus U$ is fine.

Comment: You could even do a direct proof.  Being linearly independent means that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbb v_i = 0$ implies that $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = 0$.  So, up to reindexing $V$, let $U$ be the $k$ first vector of $V$ and let $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \mathbb v_i = 0$. Then you have  $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \mathbb v_i +  \sum_{i=k+1}^n 0 \mathbb v_i = 0$, which by the linear independence of $V$ means that $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_k = 0 = 0 = \dots = 0 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @CaveJohnson good call, I mixed that up.  Also thanks Lærne, I figured with the contradiction being simple, there was probably a direct proof available, but I was struggling to understand why it worked. Your comment is helping me accept its truth!